# Kohana URL (segmented)

Tags: php, kohana

On Kohana 2.3.4 I use the query string for parameters and use the input class to get the values.

> localhost/home?id=1234

Now that I migrated to Kohana 3.3.0, I am having a lot of trouble with how the segmented URL works.

**I want to achieve this:**

> localhost/home/1234

My Controller Home:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_Template {
    public function action_index($id) {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

From my understanding of segmented URLs, my controller should have something like this:

```
public function action_details($id) {
    //code here
}
```

But this would mean that the link is `localhost/home/details/1234`. I would prefer not to have the details action anymore. How can I do it? Sorry, at the moment I wrote this, Kohana seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.3, you cant use params in actions. All you need is `&$this->request->param('id')`. See http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters

Comment: Wow thank you, I understand it better now with the bootstrap and routing.. I've set my routing to '(<controller>(/<param>))' and then I used $this->request->param('param', null) to get the ID.. thanks a lot!

Comment: `param()` returns NULL by default, so you can pass just a param name.